# MySQL Workbench table export UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export one of our production tables so I can import it to a local db to experiment with.

But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
> self.func()
> File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_power_export_wizard.py", line 273, in start_export
> retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
> File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 302, in start
> ret = self.start_export()
> File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 398, in start_export
> output.writerow(row)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
> ERROR: Export data to file: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

I am running version 8.0.26 on MacOS.

Edit:
I used the following options:

- File Format: `csv`
- Field Separator: `;`
- Line Separator: `LF`
- Enclose Strings In: `"`
- null and NULL as SQL keyword: `YES`

I also tried using `,` as separator but no luck.

**However, exporting as JSON works!** It seems slower though :/

Comment: report it to oracle, this is a bug in the python script

Comment: And do post a link to the bug report here, because it also happens in version 8.0.28 

Answer (score 13):

If you are using on mac, try starting mySql Workbench from command.

```
open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

Comment: The year is 2024. The OP is still a problem. Why did this actually fix it??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and exporting it to JSON instead of CSV helped. You can use JSON for importing data just like CSV.